# Scala raw strings error in unicode escape

Tags: string, scala, unicode, unicode-escapes

In a Scala String need to include this literal verbatim: `\usepackage{x}`. Thus, desired would be that for

```
val s = """ ... \usepackage{X} ... """

println(s)
... \usepackage{X} ...
```

Attempts so far include,

```
scala> """\usepackage{X}"""
<console>:1: error: error in unicode escape
       """\usepackage{X}"""
            ^

scala> raw"""\usepackage{X}"""
<console>:1: error: error in unicode escape
       raw"""\usepackage{X}"""
               ^
```

Single double-quoted strings prove unsuccessful as well.

Following http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html , a working example includes

```
scala> raw"a\nb"
res1: String = a\nb
```

which does not cover unicode cases.

Comment: If you have an answer, do not edit your original question, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to be facing issue [**SI-4706**: Unicode literal syntax thwarts common use cases for triple-quotes](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4706).

In Scala, unicode escape sequences are processed not only inside character or string literals. It may not be obvious that the following code would work:

```
scala> 5 \u002B 10
res0: Int = 15
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good way around this if you don't want to disable unicode escapes completely (`-Xno-uescape`, only available until Scala 2.13.1, see [PR #8282](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8282) and [ee8c1ef8](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/ee8c1ef8f1e712542b9d5fe01bc5cea21e0227c1)).

One of workarounds suggested in the SI-4706 issue is separating the backslash character:

```
scala> """\""" + """usepackage{X}"""
res1: String = \usepackage{X}
```

Comment: Thanks for the '-Xno-uescape' tip. \u even in comments causes compilations to fail.

Comment: You can also Unicode-encode both the backslash and the 'u': `"""\u005c\u0075"""` correctly gives `\u`.

Comment: @ComFreek I'm three years late to the party, but that deserves a standalone answer