# How to put unicode characters into strings when using -Xno-escape

Tags: scala, unicode

I use literals like `"""\usepackage{x}"""`, so I compile my Scala code with `-Xno-uescape`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058549/scala-raw-strings-error-in-unicode-escape).

However, in another part of the same project, I need to remove the BOM from a string. I cannot input the BOM in any way (for example, `'\ufeff'` does not work because of the compiler switch). So I am at a loss how to declare the BOM as a literal value in my code on one hand and be able to use `"""\usepackage{x}"""` on the other hand.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toChar` method on `Int`:

```
0xFEFF.toChar == '\uFEFF' // true
```

Combine it with string interpolation if you need to inline it somewhere:

```
s"${0x20ac.toChar}665.11" // €665.11
```

Or `map` if you need a character sequence:

```
Vector(0xAB, 0x2022, 0xBB).map(_.toChar).mkString // «•»
```